# Apex Scheduler Help

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I wish to write an apex class that runs 30 days after a `status` has been changed to `Resolved` this should change `status` field from `Resolved` to `Closed`.

The reason for not using a `workflow rule` is because this field change is causing salesforce to reach a `soql` query limit and it's not updating another `status` field further down the line.

Essentially changing the `Status` from `Resolved` to `Closed` should change the `SLA Status` from `OK` to `Met` but this is not working.

I have been advised to write an `apex scheduler`. I'm not from a coding background and was wondering if somebody could help me get started with this please. I know the start of the code should look something like this;

```
public class s_class1 implements Schedulable{
    public static void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
```

But I'm not sure how the rest of it should look and thought i'd ask on here before I go too far down the rabbit hole!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Glenn

Comment: Even if you change this field from Resolved to Closed in apex via scheduler then also you would be getting soql query limit. I would suggest you should optimize existing code so that SOQL query limit won't come.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Glenn. There's a Trailhead module on Asynchronous Apex that you should find helpful. Essentially your writing a batch class that implements the Schedulable Interface. If you use search at the top right of the page or look at the related posts to right of the page, you'll easily find sample code that should help you get started. This is the kind of class that honestly, you'd want to just run daily and have it query for records that need updated.

Comment: As @KiranMachhewar mentioned, this is probably a place where you want to optimize your code and create the WFR instead. in SFDC, whenever possible, you should try to use clicks, not code.